# Weakening hypothesis without a cut

Tags: coq

I often find myself in the following situation, where I have proven a lemma which is an implication:

```
Lemma L1: A -> B
```

where in fact the equivalence `A <-> B` is provable, but the implication `B -> A` is a trivial and not a very interesting result. Then in the course of designing some proof, I end up with the hypothesis:

```
H : A
```

and I actually want to use `B`. I can use a cut:

```
cut (B).
```

and proceed from there, but I am sure there is a quicker way to formally weaken hypothesis `H`, replacing statement `A` by `B`.

What I have been doing lately is go back to my lemma and prove both side of the implication.

```
Lemma L1 : A <-> B
```

then use a simple `rewrite L1 in H`. So this works for equivalences but not in general of course. So how do I weaken an hypothesis without a `cut` from a simple implication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do that is to use `apply L1 in H.`.

```
Variables A B : Prop.
Lemma L1 : A -> B. Admitted.

Theorem theorem : A -> 1 = 1.
  intros H.
  apply L1 in H.
```

The last line turns `H : A` into `H : B`.

Answer (score 1):

indeed, this is a common occurrence and some Coq plugins such as ssreflect provide special support for it, called "hypothesis view". IMHO a rewrite may not be so bad in your case.

Coq 8.5 introduces an experimental `p%term` feature to perform "views" on the hypotheses, so you could do:

```
Variables (A B C : Prop).
Hypothesis U : A -> B.

Lemma L1 : A -> B.
intros h%U.
```

but note that this feature is likely to be removed. Of course, if you are open to using the ssreflect tactic language views are an essential feature and you can just do:

```
Variables (A B C : Prop).
Hypothesis U : A -> B.

Lemma L1 : A -> B.
by move=> /U.
```

Views in ssreflect prodive many more goodies, for instance, if you have a hypothesis `B` and a lemma `U : A -> B -> C` you can usually apply `/U`, etc... see the manual for more details.